# Angular: Can I completely disable sanitizing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to completely disable sanitizingof HTML?

What I want to achieve is to have in my controller:

```
$scope.greeting = '<h2>Hello World</h2>'
```

And in my view

```
{{greeting}}
```

I cannot (and dont want to) use ng-bind-html and such, I want to disable sanitizing all together.

Just to give some more context - I am preparing simple "framework wrap around" for developing a template for specific system.

When you develop template for this system, they have pre-defined snippets that you can place on your page by writing "{{something}}" but it is not running on angular (probably mustache or something).

Now the template can be developed only online and it is VERY user-unfriendly proccess. Therefore I setup simple project in angular with corresponding routes etc, so everyone can develop the template on their machine and then simply copy it over to the system.

That is why in the template files it shouldnt be noticable that its done in angular, it just be as close to their system as possible.

One last note - I did try:

```
myApp.config(['$sceProvider',function($sceProvider){
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
}]);
```

Didn't do anything for me

Comment: @Donal how is that helpful?

Comment: you need to upgrade your angular version to take use of this feature..you should have angular 1.3+ version

Comment: @pankajparkar I am using 1.3.15

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### **Yes you can turn off SCE but this will not cause your strings to be interpolated into HTML**

Using your scenario:

```
  $scope.movie = {title:"<h1>Egghead.io AngularJS, Binding</h1>",
 src:"http://www.youtube.com/embed/Lx7ycjC8qjE"};
```

and interpolating the title directly without use of `ng-bind-html="movie.title"`

```
<p>{{movie.title}}</p>
```

will produce this

```
<h1>Egghead.io AngularJS Binding</h1>
```

**Straight interpolation seems to be sanitized, but it is actually not compiled.**

An interpolated string with **HTML** is treated as a string unless compiled within a directive.

Other frameworks tend to be "string based" (they feed the browser directly), whereas **AngularJS** is "DOM based", it compiles your **HTML** and manages it aggressively with scopes and watch events. Martin Fowler refers to this as Template **[View vs Transform View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/twoStepView.html)**.

**HTML can be compiled within Directives, but can only be interpolated in markup and controllers**

---

**I've created 2 Plunkers trying to access an "insecure url" which just means I interpolated a url  in `ng-src` without using `$sce.trustAs`**

**Exhibit 1: [Plunker 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/JZdd7cLNWqirrwGIKKgS?p=preview)** *SCE disabled during config*

Markup interpolates "insecure url":

```
    <p>{{movie.title}}</p>
    <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" ng-src="{{movie.src}}" allowfullscreen frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

App disables `$sceProvider`

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);
app.config(['$sceProvider',function($sceProvider){
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
}]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {

  $scope.movie = {src:"http://www.youtube.com/embed/Lx7ycjC8qjE", title:"Egghead.io AngularJS Binding"};
});
```

The "unsafe" URL is interpolated without error. The Video is displayed.

---

**Exhibit 2: [Plunker 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/GFRpFqysxiuGHH9i2QHb?p=preview)** *`app.config` commented out, ergo, using Default SCE settings*

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);
//app.config(['$sceProvider',function($sceProvider){
//    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
//}]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {

  $scope.movie = {src:"http://www.youtube.com/embed/Lx7ycjC8qjE", title:"Egghead.io AngularJS Binding"};
});
```

**Error:**

> Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{movie.src}} Error:
>   [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by
>   $sceDelegate policy.  URL: http://www.youtube.com/embed/Lx7ycjC8qjE

Comment: That is very good and detailed answer, thank you for that, unfortunately it deals only with one case - urls. What I really need though is HTML. Also you are using angular directives, I need it 100% without directives. You can see that in my question description. But you might be right and I might have run into case when even disabeling $sce doesn't do anything. - I will chekc if I have same version of angular and sanitize

Comment: @Tom, agreed, this is only 1 use case. But I didn't have your use case to demonstrate. The reason is b/c `{{greeting}}`. I changed Plunker 2, to simply user `src="{{movie.src}}"`, and created the same error. I should have used `src` rather than `ng-src` considering your concerns. I chose the use case of `ng-src` because **passing interpolated strings to ng-src is the most strictly enforced SCE behavior** whereas, straight interpolation `{{greeting}}` is the least enforced and usually just succeeds. So without your specific use case (the data that causes break) I would not have caused an error.

Comment: @Tom, try the new Plunker using just `src="{{movie.src}}"` and give me more specifics of the html that causes the SCE error http://plnkr.co/edit/GFRpFqysxiuGHH9i2QHb?p=preview

Comment: But I am not trying to do anything with src... just wrap your movie.title in <h1> tag: $scope.movie = {title: '<h1>Whatever</h1>'} and you will see that on page you will get the tags printed out , not rendered html

Comment: @Tom, I'm sorry, I should have realized what you wanted. My answer was wrong from hindsight. I took your Question about SCE too literally instead of seeing the obvious. Straight interpolation is ALWAYS Sanitized. Or, more accurately, interpolation does not cause compilation. Compiling strings into **HTML** can ONLY be done on directives. It is not SCE related, as polices directives and services SCE, raising errors from inappropriate use of $interpolateservice or a directive. You need ng-bind-html, $interpolate, or $compile to interpolate HTML. I have altered my answer to explain better.

Comment: Cool, so my question is: Is it really impossible? or there could be a way around that?

Comment: @Tom **impossible to compile HTML in angular without using a Directive**

Comment: @Tom did I fall short of answering your question?

Comment: Well you did post good answer, but it doesnt solve my problem... I accept your answer that it is impossible, but is it really? I didnt have time to dig through the angular yet, but I am sure that there is somewhere where I coould remove escaping. I also do not appreciate you posting comments about me asking not correctly due to my lack of knowledge or whatever was said. Just because you did not understand my question doesnt mean that "I am still learning angular".. Anyway I will accept your answer just for the sake of something being accepted...

Answer (score 2):

A while ago I managed to render some HTML returned from a service like this:

```
$scope.greeting = $sce.trustAsHtml('<h2>Hello World</h2>');
```

And in your HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlGreeting"></div>
```

Don't forget to inject the $sce service in the controller.

EDIT here's a example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b78hkssn/2/

Comment: That's weird, I used it sparingly in a recent project. Does it fail silently or returns some error? Do you have any clue at all of why it doesn't work?

Comment: `trustAsHtml` works to disable SCE, It will not compile. HTML cannot be "fed" to a browser with AngularJS. Angular does not work with passive templating. The framework circumvents the browser's HTML interpreter.

Comment: I've included a link to a fiddle in my answer that shows how it works.

Comment: You are using a directive `ng-bind-html`. This directive specifically compiles the contents to **HTML**. Directives are the only way to compile strings to Markup in **AngularJS**. OP apparently cannot use any directives for this solution. Check his first comment on my answer **I need it 100% without directives.** Otherwise, his original approach of disabling SCE would make trust unnecessary.

Comment: You're right, @DaveAlperovich, I neglected that part. Sorry.

Comment: No, it wasn't obvious at all. I realized it only after OP's response. The Question is misleading b/c OP is still learning Angular. Your answer (as applied to Question formed) is very good. I wish more of the 5 digit rep users were as thorough.

Answer (score 0):

Try enhance or change standard behavior of $sce using decorators:

```
 angular
  .module( appName, [ ] )
  .config([ "$provide", function( $provide )
  {
        // Use the `decorator` to enhance or change behaviors of original service instance; 

        $provide.decorator( '$sce', [ "$delegate", function( $delegate )
        {
            // Save the original $sce.parseAsHtml
            var parseAsHtml= $sce.parseAsHtml;

            $delegate.parseHtml= function( ) {
              // Implements your custom behavior...
            };

            return $delegate;
        }]);
  }]);
```

Comment: Tried that, still doesnt work. I have done a lot of digging into angular code, and it seems that angular automatically replaces every {{}} expression with text node which basically prevents the HTML render. would that be possible?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find another way of solving the problem without using any directives.

Basically I use an injector to use the $compile service.

JS:

```
angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    $('.html-content').append($compile('<h2>Hello World</h2>')($rootScope));
});
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davguij/tby59sk7/1/

Comment: So you are bypassing the whole Angular pipeline and executing that code? So the HTML is not tracked and angular becomes useless. So we're backed to doing jQuery code now.